# How to combine values filter with a Queryset of a certain Foreignkey field on my Django Model

Tags: django, django-views, wagtail

I have this field in my model:

```py
class PlayerDetailPage(Page):
    picture = models.ForeignKey('wagtailimages.Image', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='+', help_text=_('Player profile picture.'))
```

And I want to create a inclusion tag, where I access different fields on this Wagtail page model. For db efficiency I use values but on the `picture` field I want the full query set. Not just a value in a dictionary because I need to render the image.

Right now I have this view:

```py
PlayerDetailPage.objects.values('title', 'path' , 'slug', 'owner__age', 'owner__nationality', )
```

So far so good, I am pulling only the fields I need and I get a nice dictionary with one query. However for the `picture` field I want the full query set because it is a Wagtail picture field. It has some nice render options attached. How can I combine this in my view to get the best db efficient query?

And unfortunately direct url is not a field in the image model I guess it is a property, I tried `picture__url` but that resolved in:

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'url' into field. Choices are: collection, collection_id, created_at, file, file_hash, file_size, focal_point_height, focal_point_width, focal_point_x, focal_point_y, height, id, renditions, tagged_items, tags, title, uploaded_by_user, uploaded_by_user_id, width
```

My view:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('wdashboard/tags/player_widget.html', takes_context=True)
def player_widget(context):

    qs = PlayerDetailPage.objects.values('title', 'path' , 'picture__file', 'slug', 'owner__age', 'owner__nationality', )
    for ins in qs:
        ins['picture'] = Image(file=ins['picture__file'])

        return {'values1': qs,'request': context['request'],}
```

Comment: Please add Image model. And do you need to get urls only for images?

Comment: The Wagtail image model is a special image handler, you can read more about it here: http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.5/topics/images.html, I do need only the url however the image model does not have this, I think it is generated as a property so I can't filter on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing you are looking for is not possible without a tricky solution IMHO. The reason is that `values` method runs a very well defined query only once on db and then converts results into `dict`. So you are never going to get original `PlayerDetailPage` object but a dict. For example if you have a model `MyModel` and you do following

```
x = MyModel.objects.get(id=1)
print(type(x)) # <class 'MyModel'>
```

But for values the case is different

```
x = MyModel.objects.values('id').get(id=1)
print(type(x)) # <class 'dict'>
```

So you lose original object and get a dict.

**A little clever solution**

If you have no other choice then using `values`, I would suggest following solution.

Build your query and also get **data** you need from `Image` model.

```
 qs = PlayerDetailPage.objects.values('picture__name') # assume there is a name field.
```

Now loop over `qs`, initialize an `Image` object, (**don't save it**) and add it to your dictionary like this

```
from wagtail.images.models import Image

for ins in qs:
    ins['picture'] = Image(name=ins['picture__name'])
```

Now you have an `picture` in your values qs as instance and you can use *nice render options attached* with it.

Comment: Awesome. Very clever solution. Thank you very much!

Comment: I tried it now but I get a traceback: `The 'file' attribute has no file associated with it.` Any ideas what is going wrong?

Comment: What fields you  are trying to get for picture attribute?

Comment: I replaced `picture__name` in your example with `picture__title` because image model does not have a name field. Then in the template I do `{% for entry in qs %}` then I should be able to render the image with the Wagtail image tag right? `{% image entry.picture fill-100x100-c1 as pic %}` however this is not working.

Comment: As you can see [here](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/master/wagtail/images/models.py#L62). wagtail Image model has a file field. where it saves image as database field. You need to get value of that field and pass it to `Image` instance.

Comment: Ah ok thank you. But now I get `save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object 'image'.`

Comment: I added my current view to the original post. Maybe I am doing something wrong, could you check please?

Comment: Hi, as I can see you are using wagtail cms there must be some other things wagtail doing automatically behind the scene. I would have to reproduce your problem and debug then I would be able to track exact problem. I'll update you on this later after doing that.